# Article options overridden by global settings

Tags: joomla-4.x, articles

I would like to control the display of fields like author, modified date, etc. on a per-article basis in addition to the global options.

However, even when I set the options in the article, they do not take effect. [This discussion](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/cannot-override-global-article-settings) does provide some insight, but it deals with articles that are accessed through the menu. I am not accessing the articles that way, but rather through a link on another page. I am quite baffled as to how I can get the article options to take effect, rather than having the display use only the global options.

Can anyone provide some pointers for solving this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [this discussion](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17779/article-settings-priority-global-menu-article?rq=1) I have found the answer.

I had a menu item pointing to the article (single article menu item type). When that is the case, the display options under the menu item take precedence over the options set in the article. The menu item was there only for administrative purposes and that is why I missed it.

When using menu items for administrative purposes only (like assigning template styles), it's worth remembering that their settings can determine how the article is displayed.

Comment: Looking at the discussion link you quote in your answer I think that the accepted answer there might be wrong. If you think the same it would be worth you adding a comment there to point people in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, Robbie. I think the answer there needed a qualification, rather than being wrong. I have added a comment there for clarification.